# jquery tabs are not full width

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm using jquery .tabs() to display graphs (one per tab). When I load the page, the first tab shows up with the graph exactly as it should be. When I click on any of the other tabs, the graph is completely squished down to about 30px wide. I have my css set so that the graph width should be 100%. When I click inspect element, the graph expands to fill the entire space, as it should. If I then click on the next tab, or back to the original one, the graphs are again squished until I inspect them. If I set the width in my css to be an exact width instead of 100%, then they show up fine. However, I would like my pages to be responsive to screen size, so this isn't an option that I want. Here is the html and javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
</script>
<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">APIXU</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-4">Open Weather Map</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-5">Weather Underground</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <div id="div7" class="errorChart"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-4">
        <div id="div8" class="errorChart"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-5">
        <div id="div9" class="errorChart"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The graphs are drawn inside the "div7", "div8", and "div9" divs. If my css is set like this:

```
div.errorChart{
    min-width: 500px;
    height: 450px;
}
```

Then the graphs are a reasonable size, but don't expand beyond the 500px, even when the available space is about 1000 px on my screen. (If I click inspect element, then they expand.) If I set the css like this:

```
div.errorChart{
    width: 100%;
    height: 450px;
}
```

Then the graphs are completely squished until I inspect them. Does anyone know why this is happening? Do I have to set the width to a fixed number, or is there a way to keep it responsive?